# Do I need proof of accommodation for my ENTIRE Schengen trip?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen, airports, bookings, tourist-visas

If I want to go to a Schengen country like Germany as a US citizen, do I need to show reservations for an ENTIRE 3-month trip, or just proof that I have somewhere to stay upon entering the country? Is a two week reservation good enough?

Comment: Where do you get that as US citizen you need a reservation? Is that a covid requerement?

Comment: No. Means of subsistence for the entire stay must be shown. Schengen Border Code Article 6(1)(c).

Comment: @MarkJohnson Means of subsistence is proof that you can afford your stay. You don't need a reservation, just proof that you can pay for it. Of course if you have very limited resources and can't afford hotels, then some justification that someone will host you (for free) becomes relevant, but not in the general case.

Comment: @jcaron You don't need to explain what means of subsistence means to me and the *No* of my comment is the answer to the OP's question about the need of reservations

Answer (score 1):

Unless it is a special Covid requerement, no reservations are needed for US citizens to enter the Schengen area on a visa free visit.

It is often advised to make a reservation for the first night but even that is not needed for the entry stamp in your passport.

The border officials do sometimes ask to show proof of enough money but even that is not that often.